# Android onClickListener

Tags: java, android, sdk

SOLVED: Put my file in the wrong folder, my stupid mistake :)

Anyone knows why this won't work? It just doesn't do anything. I have everything in the Main XML defined properly i think, but i feel like something is missing here.

I am new to Java/Android developing but i was using VB.NET for a long time.

```
package com.example.myfirstapplication;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Main extends Activity{

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddOne);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubOne);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added layout. Thought it wasn't needed:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Your total is 0"
   android:layout_gravity="center" 
   android:textSize="45dp" 
   android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"/>
<Button 
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add 1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/bAddOne"    />
<Button 
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subtract 1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/bSubOne"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: And the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you include your `activity_main` layout?

Comment: try adding `@Override` to the `onClick()` method

Comment: And by what A.A means by "adding," is to put `@Override` just on the line before `public void onClick ...`

Comment: If adding `@Override` does not fix it, post your `android:id=""` for each button.

Comment: try `display.invalidate()`. This will trigger the UI to recalculate an reinitialize the Button, although it works just fine for me without.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong when you check the documentation, you'll find `public abstract void onClick()`. being `abstract` mean it should be overridden

Comment: @A.A hmm, you're right. My bad. However, I get an error putting `@Override` above onClick(), so I assumed it was an interface (and it is, so I really have no clue why it's an abstract method). The error seems to have something to do with my SDK version.

Comment: @A.A and @ChristiaandeJong The developer's Java compiler settings determine whether or not to use `@Override`; in 1.5 it's an error _to use_ it, in 1.6 it's an error _not_ to use it.

Comment: I have the Android 2.2 APK and it gets me an error.

Comment: @Sydcul I don't see a problem with any of this code. When you said "it doesn't do anything", are you implying that the `TextView` is not updated or does it throw an error?  If it is throwing an error, please post your LogCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. A quick fix is to change the name of the Activity from Main.java to **MainActivity**.java.

```
package com.example.myfirstapplication;

 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity{

      int counter;
      Button add, sub;
      TextView display;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          counter = 0;
          add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddOne);
          sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubOne);
          display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
          add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       counter++;
                       display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
                    }
               });
          sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   public void onClick(View v) {
                           counter--;
                            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
                   }
         });
     }
}
```

The reason is That in the AndroidManifest.xml the starting Activity is declared as MainActivity:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It is in the line that says:  **android:name=".MainActivity"**, and the

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

says that it is the starting and main activity.

Comment: No. look in your code. Inside Main.java. the name of the class is Main and not MainActivity.

Comment: But i think it always was called MainActivity. If i make a huge mistake, please tell me. EDIT: Ok just noted your reaction on posting this. Thank you. I'll try it out tomorrow.